# iOS Navigation Bar and UIAutomation

Tags: ios, user-interface, automated-tests

I've run into an annoying problem - we use accessibilityIdentifier along with Appium to test our cross-platform apps but, very oddly, the navigation bar in our iOS app just will NOT let its components' accessibilityIdentifier be modified. I seen that some people have work-arounds that involve simply replacing the title label and various buttons or just creating their own navigation bar equivalents, but that seems a little overkill. Has anyone found a solution to this? Does Apple have a stance on whether or not this is a bug?